# How to configure windows server to satisfy azure policy

Tags: windows, azure, group-policy, windows-server-2016, server-settings

I have an azure vm running windows server 2016. I applied to it a policy that checks vm configuration through a guest configuration extension. For example for the policy [Windows machines should meet requirements for 'Administrative Templates - Network'](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/built-in-policies/policyDefinitions/Guest%20Configuration/GuestConfiguration_AdministrativeTemplatesNetwork_AINE.json) the definition says:

> Windows machines should have the specified Group Policy settings in
> the category 'Administrative Templates - Network' for guest logons,
> simultaneous connections, network bridge, ICS, and multicast name
> resolution. This policy requires that the Guest Configuration
> prerequisites have been deployed to the policy assignment scope. For
> details, visit https://aka.ms/gcpol.

Unfortunately I have a problem with settings that have to be applied to satisfy this policy.

The question is: what should be set up on the vm according to this policy and is there some source of information about required  settings for other policies.